# How do I make my Chrome extension read a specific piece of the text of the current web page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension for finding email addresses, and I want it to grab the email when visiting a specific web page.

For example, let's say I'm visiting `http://www.sagaciousinfosystems.com/contactus.php` and execute my extension. I want it to grab the email addresses on the page, which I could then use for other things.

Comment: what have you tried yet ?
And do you want to know when someone enters an email into an input field or search the whole document for addresses?

Comment: search the whole document for addresses

Comment: now i got my plugin. when i moving from one tab to another m able to alert the url.. now i need to get the current page information to search for a particular data..

Comment: See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html and http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html